# Is the root CA certificate required in the .crt file?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, nginx

I am setting up SSL on Nginx with a free StartSSL certificate. Based on the instructions given on [this StartSSL page](https://www.startssl.com/?app=42) I created a unified certificate containing the CA's root certificate, Intermediate certificate and the one for my domain.

Testing this setup on **ssllabs** the following sections caught my eye.

[image]

[image]

So I thought if the root CA certificate is in the trust store why should I add it to my `.crt` file and removed it from my server.

Checking again I found that the size of the certificate reduced and the **Chain issues - Contains anchor** disappeared.

I tested the site on Firefox and IE11 and no SSL errors were displayed.

Did I setup deploy certificate right?

Why does that page on StartSSL instruct to add the root CA certificate too if it is already present in the browsers' certificates store?

Comment: Your question is already answered here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24561/ssltest-chain-issues-contains-anchor

Comment: @binaryanomaly You're right! How do I "close" this question now?

Comment: Click `answer your question` down below

Comment: @A.Jesin Just wait a bit. The question will be closed on its own.