# SSL/TLS: How to fix "Chain issues: Contains anchor"

Tags: tls, nginx, ocsp

I just ran a quick test at ssllabs.com: got A+, which I'm happy about.

However there's one thing I don't know how to "fix":
My site supports OCSP stapling and ssllabs keeps telling me: Chain issues: Contains anchor.
I know this is just a "warning" in the sense that it slows down the connection a bit.

nginx config:

```
..
ssl_certificate             public.crt;
ssl_certificate_key         private.key;
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;
ssl_trusted_certificate     my-chain.pem;
..
```

Where:
- **public.crt** is the public certificate I got from StartSSL
- **private.key** the certificate's private key
- **my-chain.pem** (ssllabs calls this: "Additional Certificates (if supplied)") consist of:

```
1.) StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA  
2.) StartCom Certification Authority
```

I found a site which also uses StartCom (StartSSL) certificates, supports OCSP stapling, but does not have the issue described above.

This site's "Additional Certificates":

```
1.) StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
```

I've tried the same: Only put "StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA" to my-chain.pem.
However then ssllabs says: **OCSP stapling: No** So this seems to completely break OCSP stapling.

Any idea?

## EDIT:

### Finally fixed!

```
ssl_certificate = Site certificate + StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA  
ssl_trusted_certificate = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA + StartCom Certification Authority
```

Comment: BTW, just as a word of caution to others. When Ben says `ssl_certificate = Site certificate + StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA` that is not actually a directive in the config. + signs are not allowed.

You need to merge it in the files themselves. Would be neat though if the syntax was accepted

Comment: I know you've stated that you know it's a warning, but for anyone else coming across this there isn't necessarily a problem sending the trust anchor: see http://security.stackexchange.com/a/24566/7043 which covers this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_trusted_certificate) the `ssl_trusted_certificate` parameter contains trusted CA certificates *used to verify client certificates and OCSP responses if ssl_stapling is enabled* and *the list of these certificates will not be sent to clients*.

Therefore I think that what ssllabs calls "Additional Certificates (if supplied)" are the certificates in the `ssl_certificate` file which are not the server certificate.

For me:

`public.crt` should contain these 2 certificates:

```
1) your server certificate
2) StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
```

`my-chain.pem` should contain these 2 certificates:

```
1) StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA // required to validate the server certificate OCSP response 
2) StartCom Certification Authority  // required to validate the intermediate CA certificate OCSP response
```

Comment: So confused, what does this mean "and the list of these certificates will not be sent to clients."

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you have your site's certificate referenced by `ssl_certificate` and a file containing both the intermediate cert and the CA cert referenced by `ssl_trusted_certificate`

Instead, what you should do is, have a file containing both your site's cert and the intermediate cert referenced by `ssl_certificate` and ONLY the CA cert referenced by `ssl_trusted_certificate`

ie:

**public.crt** should contain:

```
1) your site's cert, issued by StartCom
2) StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
```

and **my-chain.pem** should contain:

```
1) StartCom Certification Authority
```

Yes, the is the oppposite of how Apache does things. But nginx != apache.

Comment: Just tried that. Again -- ssllabs says: __OCSP stapling: No__

Comment: Some versions on nginx won't staple until after the site has been loaded at least once. So, if you restart nginx, and then immediately run the test, you'll get a "No" but if you re-run the test again, you should get a "yes".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It indeed seems that nginx does not share the OCSP information between all worker threads. I finally fixed the "issue" by following Jcs' answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79519/ssl-tls-how-to-fix-chain-issues-contains-anchor/79538#79538